# support qt a 18bit display?

Tags: qt, embedded-linux, framebuffer

It is possible to control a 18 bit display with QT?
The display gets his data in 3 bytes per pixel (18bit), but only the first 6 bits per byte are evaluated for colorinformation.

Comment: another approach of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783523

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By 1st 6 bits do you mean the 6 MSBs or LSBs? That is, are the valid bits `[RRRRRR--][GGGGGG--][BBBBBB--]` or `[--RRRRRR][--GGGGGG][--BBBBBB]`?

If it the former (6 MSBs) you can just feed the display `QImage::Format_RGB888` data. The LSBs will just be ignored. If it's the later, you can try [`QImage::Format_RGB666`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qimage.html#Format-enum), which uses LSBs.

Comment: Yeaa .. I digged into qt-sources and have seen that I have to use MSB-bits, but the display understand LSB bits only. I have tested with QImage::Format_RGB666 but I have had color misplacements. How I have to handle this situation?

Comment: If you mean the RGB channels are somehow swapped, note that RGB888 and RGB666 both require the channels in RGB byte sequence. Byte sequence can be different than the byte order in a 32-bit int depending on the endian.

Comment: OK. We have solved the Problem with the hardware. Previously, at the time of writing of my question, we had the 18bit LCD interface connected with the DIU over 24 pins. DIU0-5 for blue, DIU8-16 for green and DIU16-21 for red. The DIU-PINS 6,7,14,15,22 and 23 are not connected. Now we connect DIU0-17 with the LCD and all works nice.